# How to add submenu to Wordpress plugin in the same Directory of main Plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, admin-menu

I have created a plugin and now i want to add a third party plugin inside of the Main Plugin menu, so it can be submenu. How do you make the second plugin appear?

**Directory Setup**:

> /wp-content/plugins/main/
>
> /wp-content/plugins/main/My_builder <----Second Plugin

**What i have:**

```
function Main_admin_exist() {
  add_menu_page('Main', 'Main', 'manage_options', 'main', 'Main_Dashboard', plugins_url( 'Main/images/icon.png' ));
} add_action('admin_menu', 'Main_admin_exist');

/*Add Sub Menu or Third Parties Plugin to Main*/
function mainThirdPartyPlugin(){
    add_submenu_page('main', 'SecondPlugin', 'My Builder', 'manage_options' , 'SecondPlugin', 'SecondPlugin');
}add_action('admin_menu', 'mainThirdPartyPlugin');
```

Comment: It'll help if you case also post what's not working. Are you getting an error? What do you expect and what's happening instead?

Comment: It is adding two menus under `Main`: `Main` and `My Builder`.  What result are you expecting?

Comment: @Nilambar Yes, the menu appear but the content of the second plugin is not appearing.

Comment: Oh, you mean, you just want to add menu link of second plugin that will redirect to page of second plugin?

Comment: Yes, but the second plugin folder is within the main plugin folder

Comment: @Nilambar I have update the post, about directories setup

Comment: If by any means, embedded plugin is shown in the menu. I am not sure it will work as expected.

Comment: @Nilambar maybe i can do a php include or require, but then when i click on my builder i need to know where it land, so i can know the path for include. Do you know how to do that? And i see somewhere where add_submenu_page(); can add function at last param, that how i wanna include the path

Comment: Is this one fits you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116296/22728 ?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I have done that it doesn't show the page of the second plugin, but it does put it as submenu under the main plugin menu.